# DocuSign - best option for multiple users / contracts

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

Can anybody point me in the correct way to set up Docusign.

My environment is a php/laravel/vuejs Estate Agents site. We have our website that is used by multiple agencies/branches.

Our customers (estate agents) currently send out by email a pdf document that the recipient receives, can print out, sign and return. Or just print and post with a SAE for it to be returned signed.

We would like to offer an electronic version but not sure on the best way to proceed.

What I need to easily implement is a way to quickly and easily allow any agent to email any vendor/landlord/tenant a unique document for them to sign (sales contract/tenancy agreement).

In my mind, I thought that I'd be able to create the PDF, populated with custom fields already stating the Vendor/Landlord/Tenant, areas for signatures/dates and send it via Docusign for the recipient to then sign.

I found this option for Laravel 8:-

https://blog.codehunger.in/embedded-signing-docusign-laravel/

BUT, when it sends a PDF, you need to log in, add each field and then send it.

With the above in mind, does this mean that all our agents require a Docusign account for logging in, amending each PDF to add the signature/initials/date signed so when signed, all parties (inc agent) receives an email copy of the signed document?

Or, is there a better way to implement Docusign?

I can't see the template option working as each document needs populating with unique information (address/vendor/landlord/tenant/guarantor).

Just trying to work out the best way to automate this option from our system. Or, would you recommend an alternative system?

Hope I've explained it enough for someone to answer! If not, let me know!

Cheers in advance
Carl.

Comment: You might be more likely to find an answer on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: @R_Dax thanks, will post it on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a fully completed application quickstart project that shows a few different ways that you could approach this, [listed here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/).  Create a developer account if you haven't already done so and use this page to select PHP to generated a completed application for you.  This will save time in having to setup an integration key and the local redirects for your machine.  It will download a PHP application that you can use for boilerplate code on your specific integration that you intend to build.

To answer your specific question,

> My environment is a php/laravel/vuejs Estate Agents site. We have our
> website that is used by multiple agencies/branches.
>
> Our customers (estate agents) currently send out by email a pdf
> document that the recipient receives, can print out, sign and return.
> Or just print and post with a SAE for it to be returned signed.
>
> We would like to offer an electronic version but not sure on the best
> way to proceed.
>
> What I need to easily implement is a way to quickly and easily allow
> any agent to email any vendor/landlord/tenant a unique document for
> them to sign (sales contract/tenancy agreement).

Documents are sent to signers using what is called an envelope. Envelope objects are generated and passed through to our API to either sign a set of documents on the spot (using a redirect to a docusign hosted page) or by emailing them to the recipient to sign. [Example 2](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Controllers/Examples/eSignature/EG002SigningViaEmail.php#L96) on the PHP quickstart will send an envelope to your signer and a cc.  Using auto tagging, you can specify the names and values of your vendors, landlords, and tenants, and pass those through to the document(s) within your envelope to have the various parties sign and/or receive carbon copies.

```
    # document 1 (html) has sign here anchor tag **signature_1**
    # document 2 (docx) has sign here anchor tag /sn1/
    # document 3 (pdf)  has sign here anchor tag /sn1/
    #
    # The envelope has two recipients.
    # recipient 1 - signer
    # recipient 2 - cc
    # The envelope will be sent first to the signer.
    # After it is signed, a copy is sent to the cc person.
    #
    # create the envelope definition
    $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
       'email_subject' => 'Please sign this document set'
    ]);
    $doc1_b64 = base64_encode($this->clientService->createDocumentForEnvelope($args));
    # read files 2 and 3 from a local directory
    # The reads could raise an exception if the file is not available!
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents(self::DEMO_DOCS_PATH . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_docx']);
    $doc2_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents(self::DEMO_DOCS_PATH . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_pdf']);
    $doc3_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);

    # Create the document models
    $document1 = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $doc1_b64,
        'name' => 'Order acknowledgement',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'html',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    $document2 = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $doc2_b64,
        'name' => 'Battle Plan',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'docx',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '2'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    $document3 = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $doc3_b64,
        'name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '3'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
    $envelope_definition->setDocuments([$document1, $document2, $document3]);


    # Create the signer recipient model
    $signer1 = new Signer([
        'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
        'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"]);
    # routingOrder (lower means earlier) determines the order of deliveries
    # to the recipients. Parallel routing order is supported by using the
    # same integer as the order for two or more recipients.

    # create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents
    $cc1 = new CarbonCopy([
        'email' => $args['cc_email'], 'name' => $args['cc_name'],
        'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2"]);

    # Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
    # We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
    #
    # The DocuSign platform searches throughout your envelope's
    # documents for matching anchor strings. So the
    # signHere2 tab will be used in both document 2 and 3 since they
    #  use the same anchor string for their "signer 1" tabs.
    $sign_here1 = new SignHere([
        'anchor_string' => '**signature_1**', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20']);
    $sign_here2 = new SignHere([
        'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 'anchor_units' =>  'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20']);

    # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tabs) to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    $signer1->setTabs(new Tabs([
        'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here1, $sign_here2]]));

    # Add the recipients to the envelope object
    $recipients = new Recipients([
        'signers' => [$signer1], 'carbon_copies' => [$cc1]]);
    $envelope_definition->setRecipients($recipients);

    # Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
    # To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
    $envelope_definition->setStatus($args["status"]);

    return $envelope_definition;
```

The PHP Quickstart itself is an MVC application that is fully working. You'll most likely want to look at the views code for example 2 which is acting like an html form via a twig template. Depending on what you're doing, you'll either have this data pre-populated with the vendor/landlord information, and you'll have some input fields for the tenant (or some combination based on your business need). Your form will then fire on the controller as a post request which will then trigger sending an envelope. For OAuth, use [JWT Grant authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) with a single administrator account so that you can generate a fresh access token as needed, across the application.

Comment: thanks for that information, I am currently working on my system, and once at a point for the above, I will code according.

Comment: Can I ask you some questions about how Docusign works?

I have my developer account, I have hard coded all my account details in to begin with, but once we are happy with how the system works, and it's gone live (I presume with assistance from Docusign)

Do I still use the same integrator key but our clients email/password?
Does each client use our template and then we just populate the custom fields accordingly?
How can I create custom fields that are associated to everyone not each recipient?
Is there an API to return all custom fields?

Comment: Each app should be delegated its own Integrator Key and either secret if using authorization code grant or an RSA key for JWT grant.  The email and password are provided by each client if you wish to use Authorization code grant and just once the very first time if using JWT.

Comment: it is possible to create system-wide accessible custom fields, yes. You can query the eSignature API to list all of those available custom fields: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/customtabs/customtabs/list/ You'll need to have the specific envelopeID to lookup the custom tabs and underlying metadata: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields/list/

Comment: I've now managed to return all the custom fields, but the custom tabs api doesn't work (I've created a new question with more info).